# Nested Named Configuration for JSON Marshallers with Grails 2.4.4

Tags: json, grails, domain-driven-design, marshalling, grails-2.0

I have following Domain Classes :

```
class Domain1{
    String prop1
    Domain2 prop2
}

class Domain2{
   String prop3
}
```

And 2 Named Marshaller Configurations for each

```
JSON.createNamedConfig('PUBLIC_API'){
        it.registerObjectMarshaller(Domain1){Domain1 domain1->
             return ['key1': domain1.prop1, 'key2': domain1.prop2]
        } 
}

JSON.createNamedConfig('PUBLIC_API'){
        it.registerObjectMarshaller(Domain2){Domain2 domain2->
             return ['key1': domain2.prop3]
        } 
}
```

When I try to use this named config, the marshalling is done only on the parent domain's object, the nested/child class's marshaller doesn't even get called.

So, using this config

```
JSON.use('PUBLIC_API'){
     render domain1 as JSON
}
```

results in

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": {
       "id": 1,
       "class" : "Domain2",
       "prop3" : "value2"
   }
}
```

I couldn't find anything with respect to such usage of named marshaller configs in [grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#namedObjectMarshallers)

Has anyone worked with such usecase ? Or if this is even supported ?

Comment: Nested marshallers work fine with no named configurations, but that's not what's my use case is. I have to register at least 2 different formats per domain & I thought named config shall be a relief.

Comment: I ended up adding 3 different configurations ... a non-named config, and 2 named config to the child domain. This doesn't address the issue but is merely a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the same problem:
For my client I send similar jsons from differents domains:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Domain1) { Domain1 domain1->
            return [
                    id      : domain1.id,
                    label   : domain1.prop
            ]
        }
        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Domain2) { Domain2 domain2->
            return [
                    id         : domain2.id,
                    label      : domain2.anotherProp
            ]
        }

        render((domains1+ domains2) as JSON);
```

Maybe it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? What's (libraries + geneSets) ?

Comment: I believe you mis-read the issue. The problem is with nested associations, not rendering w.r.t the named configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try registering your marshallers in the same `createNamedConfig` block?  I don't think the second call to `createNamedConfig` will use the config you created in the first call.  Here's what I suggest:

```
JSON.createNamedConfig('PUBLIC_API'){
    it.registerObjectMarshaller(Domain1){Domain1 domain1->
         return ['key1': domain1.prop1, 'key2': domain1.prop2]
    } 

    it.registerObjectMarshaller(Domain2){Domain2 domain2->
         return ['key1': domain2.prop3]
    } 
}
```